# Yet, another "Load operation failed for query 'GetUsers'" exception

Tags: c#, silverlight, deployment, wcf-ria-services

Recently I'm deploying Silverlight RIA application. Application works fine on the test machine, problems started when I moved it to production server. Application uses Windows Authentication. Basically I reproduced test machine's environment IIS settings and then copied entire application folder and modified web config. Below I'm listing problems and symptoms I'm having:

- When I try to log in to the application from PRODUCTION server, loggin box appears. Obviously server works with the Windows domain. I **can't** log in with my domain credentials.
- When I try to log in to the application from external machine logging box also appears, this time though I **can** log in with my credentials. Mentioned exception appears (`System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Client.DomainOperationException`).
  It's very strange since in test servers I never had to pass my Windows domain credentials.

I've used fiddler to check server response for AuthenticationService.svc call:

```
@Fault5http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/envelope/none@Code@Value�Sender@Reason@Textxmllang�pl-PL@Detail@DomainServiceFaultDomainServices i)http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance@    ErrorCode��@ErrorMessage.nil�@IsDomainException�
```

Also, I've added traces to application:

```
        <source name="LANOS.Web.AuthenticationContext"
            switchValue="Information, ActivityTracing"
            propagateActivity="true">
            <listeners>
                <add name="xml" />
            </listeners>
        </source>
        <source name="System.ServiceModel"
                switchValue="Information, ActivityTracing"
                propagateActivity="true" >
            <listeners>
                <add name="xml"/>
            </listeners>
        </source>
        <source name="LANOS.Web"
                switchValue="Information, ActivityTracing"
                propagateActivity="true">
            <listeners>
                <add name="xml" />
            </listeners>
        </source>
    </sources>
```

[*.svclog is available here.](http://pastebin.pl/03182f20a3fc8ddb5de6a9ae34be03cc)

I know there are loads of answers in gooogle. However this exception is quite generic and I have not found similar question. I've tried coping DLL's and modifying web-config according to diffrent solutions in the web. Nothing helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to find the solution to this problem. 
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/896861
method 2.